# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt n(A_{n+1}-A_n) $ when $ A_n = \frac{1}{n}(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)$ and $|a_n| \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$, $n \geq 1$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying $|a_n| \leq 1$ for all $n$. Define $$ A_n = \frac{1}{n}(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)$$

for $n\geq 1$. Then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt n(A_{n+1}-A_n) $ is

A. $0$

B. $-1$

C. $1$

D. None of them

**ATTEMPT**

I tok sequence $a_n=1$ and answer came out to be 0. But how do i choose between A and D.

Thanks

Comment: First derive the identity $(n+1)A_{n+1} - nA_n = a_{n+1}$ and rearrange it to get $\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1} - A_n) = \frac{a_{n+1} - A_{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$. Now use $a_n \leq 1$ to bound $A_n$ and use this to conclude.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*} |A_{n+1} - A_n| &= \left|\frac{1}{n+1}(a_1+\dots+a_n+a_{n+1}) - \frac{1}{n}(a_1+\dots+a_n)\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1} - \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)(a_1+\dots+a_n)\right| \\
&\le\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}\right| + \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)(|a_1|+\dots+|a_n|)\\
&\le\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n(n+1)}(n)\\
&=\frac{2}{n+1}
\end{align*}
and hence
$$\left|\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1}-A_n)\right|\le\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\rightarrow 0$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|\sqrt{n}(A_{n+1}-A_n)|=\sqrt{n}\frac{|n(a_1+...+a_n+a_{n+1})-(n+1)(a_1+...+a_n)|}{n(n+1)}\\=\frac{|a_1+...+a_n-na_{n+1}|}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)}\leq\frac{2n}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)}=\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\rightarrow 0, n\rightarrow \infty$$